# How to create diagrams for papers

Tags: documentation, diagram, tex, tikz

I want to create some diagrams for some papers.

Diagrams will contain some text, e.g. some console output. I need images for using also in html files.

There is TikZ so can create images like this:

- http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/
- http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/rule-based-diagram/
- http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scenario-tree/

but as a result I get some ps/pdf files, not images.

What's more I want to generate the pictures from text files as I want to track changes in some VCS, any binary files are not suitable for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program `convert` from the ImageMagick suite can convert PDF files to other formats, like PNG. In its simplest form:

```
convert diagram.pdf diagram.png
```

See the [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for additional options.